# Return DataFrame from a function in another file

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe, variables

I'm trying to create two files: one that will create a series of dataframe, and another that will import theses dataframes to my principal file.

Is something like this:

load_data.py

```
def data_mean():
    import pandas as pd

    global mean_re5200, mean_re2000

    mean_re5200=pd.read_csv('mean_re5200.csv')
    mean_re2000=pd.read_csv('mean_re5200.csv')
```

main_project.py

```
from load_data import data_mean
```

When I run the main_project file and type data_mean() in the terminal, all seems fine, but the dataframes  aren't save as local variables that I can use them. I saw another similar quotes here in StackOverFlow, but no one was about saving dataframe, only simple variables.

How can I proceed?

Comment: The data frames *are* "simple" variables, in that you have stored a scalar "handle" to the data frame.  However, you still need to make some external visibility to them in `load_data`, just as with any other local variable.

Comment: Well, I still don't know how to proceed. If a put "return variable" in the load_data.py, the dataframes will appear in the console, but they will not be saved yet.

Comment: How does returning a value make the data frame appear in a console?  Are you confused about the difference between `return` and `print`?

Comment: Maybe, because when I add "return variable" at the final of the function and execute, the function will be executed and the results will be printed in the console, but they will don't be saved as variables. I achive this using "global", equal I did in the code posted. 

But this don't work when I try to execute this function in another file...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply try something like

**load_data.py**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":list(range(10))})
```

**main.py**

```py
from load_data import *

print(df)
```

or alternatively

**load_data.py**

```py
import pandas as pd

def data_mean():
    df0 = pd.DataFrame({"a":list(range(10))})
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({"b":list(range(10))})
    return df0, df1
```

**main.py**

```py
from load_data import data_mean

df1, df2 = data_mean()
print(df1)
```

Comment: This helps, but what I really want to know if theres a way to achieve df1 and df2 without using "df1, df2 = data_mean() ". Because if I have much more dataframes, this kind of attribution will be really unpractical.

Comment: Ciao Alessandro, this is the way it works for seaborn, scikit-learn, plotly and other. A function return only a df and it's name is not globally defined